# Which protocol to use for a barebones LAN file upload with mixed Unix and Windows clients

Tags: windows, unix, files, upload

I have a set of about 20 embedded Unix clients who physically move from time to time. When they move into the range of a specific wireless AP, they will push a certain set of files to a Windows file server in the LAN. Every client will send a 250Mib file. There will never be any remote access to this LAN.

It basically looks like a train (embedded Raspbian clients) on a traintrack collecting passengers (the files) and then dropping them off at a specific point (The windows server).

I **only** want to push files to this Windows server and get an acknowledgement that it completed or not. I don't want or need anything else. I'm not going to share files between the clients or the server, files won't be modified or anything else than just a barebones bulk upload of files. The clients will never interact in any other way with the server or files other than uploading them. The server will process these files further.

I have read the following questions and answers: [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/582153/which-file-sharing-protocol-smb-afs-nfs-smb2-smb3-is-best-for-an-mixed-client), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/14577/what-network-file-sharing-protocol-has-the-best-performance-and-reliability?rq=1), [3](https://serverfault.com/questions/310387/best-file-sharing-protocol-for-windows-clients) but found that the use cases presented there did not match mine as these all request and consider features I don't need.

To summarize: Which protocol is most suitable for solely uploading files to a server?

Comment: It is very unclear what OS the clients are running.

Comment: I have added it in; they are embedded devices running Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a protocol to transfer files. I'm going to suggest file transfer protocol would be a good place to start, or sftp if you don't trust the LAN. FTP is widely used and highly compatible.

Confirmation of receipt may be the curly problem. You can probably solve that with a client side script of some kind, or by using FTP software with that feature.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use FTP. ;) https://whydoesitsuck.com/why-does-ftp-suck/

Comment: @RyanBolger That article points out the FTP security flaws. However this question is LAN based and FTP is easy. You can use SFTP (ftp over SSH) but that adds complication.

Comment: Apologies. The comment was meant to be tongue-in-cheek. But there are more reasons to ditch FTP (and even FTPS) than just the security aspect. SFTP on the other hand is a perfectly fine protocol and has nothing to do with FTP or FTPS other than similar naming. I'd even argue that setting up an SFTP server is easier to setup and automate than FTP these days.

Answer (score 0):

Could you transfer it as a REST transaction? The file alternatively could be uploaded as part of a form/POST.